# Как взять несколько значений из вложенного списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу взять все значения из вложенного списка, а только одно значение. Как мне сделать, чтобы можно было взять несколько значений из изменяющегося списка ?

```
alltext=[{
    "name": "sample string 1",
    "relationships": [
        {
            "isBlocked": False,
            "orderIndex": 1,
            "relationship": {
                "debts": [
                    {
                        "currency": {
                            "id": "sample string2",
                            "isoCode": "string",
                            "isoNumber3": "string",
                            "name": "string"
                        },
                        #"sum"#: 0.0
                    }
                ],
                "deferment": 90,
                "id": "string",
                #"name"#: "string 1",
                "overdueDebts": [
                    {
                        "currency": {
                            "id": "string",
                            "isoCode": "string",
                            "isoNumber3": "string",
                            "name": "string"
                        },
                        #"sum"#: 1000.0
                    }
                ],
                "vendorId": "string"
            }
        },

        {
            "isBlocked": False,
            "orderIndex": 2,
            "relationship": {
                "debts": [
                    {
                        "currency": {
                            "id": "string",
                            "isoCode": "string",
                            "isoNumber3": "string",
                            "name": "string"
                        },
                        #"sum"#: 0.0
                    }
                ],
                "deferment": 90,
                "id": "string",
                "limit": 0.0,
                #"name"#: "string ",
                "overdueDebts": [
                    {
                        "currency": {
                            "id": "string",
                            "isoCode": "string",
                            "isoNumber3": "string",
                            "name": "string"
                        },
                        #"sum"#: 2000.0
                    }
                ],
                "vendorId": "string"
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Я пробовал сделать так:

```
for i in range(len(alltext)):
        ordersname.append(alltext[i]['relationships'][0]['relationship']['name'])
```

Но так берётся только первый `name`. Я понимаю, что это скорее всего из-за `[0]`, но если его убрать, то будет ошибка `not slice or str`
Также пробовал это сделать вот так:

```
Debts.append([routeDict['sum'] for routeDict in alltext[i]['relationships'][0]['relationship']['debts']])

OverdueDebts.append([routeDict['sum'] for routeDict in alltext[i]['relationships'][0]['relationship']['overdueDebts']])
```

Но здесь та же ошибка. Как мне достать все `sum` и `name` из `[relationships][relationship]`?

Comment: @Anton Abrosimov добавил. Но это должно роботать даже если там один relationship

Comment: @ Anton Abrosimov Ну если вкратцы росказать, то должно получиться примерно так. Из relationship мы достаем name, а из Debts и OverdueDebts мы достаем sum,  и выводим это все в одну струка.    `str('\n'.join(' '.join([w, str(n1), str(n2)]) for w, n1, n2 in zip(ordersname, AllSumaDebts, AllOverdueDebts)` Вот примерный образец как должно это выгледить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот тебе пример на тему ООП, разбирайся (для Python 3.7+):

Советую с этим таки разобраться. Сильно облегчает жизнь.

```
from collections import UserList
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class Order:
    """Это датакласс.
    Объект, похожий на словарь.
    (Да, я знаю, что на именованный кортеж он больше похож,
    не надо меня минусить.)
    """

    # Он может хранить следующие поля (ключи):
    name: str
    sum_debts: float
    sum_overdue: float

    def __init__(self, relationship):
        """Конструктор класса.
        Получает ветку relationship,
        достает оттуда name, sum,
        сохраняет внутри себя найденные значения.
        """
        self.name = relationship['name']
        self.sum_debts = relationship['debts'][0]['sum']
        self.sum_overdue = relationship['overdueDebts'][0]['sum']

    def __str__(self):
        """Функция печати.
        Когда вызывается print(объект)
        насамом деле происходит:
        строка = объект.__str__()
        print(строка)

        В данном случае, берутся сохраненные внутри датакласса
        name, sum_debts, sum_overdue,
        склеиваются join'ом и возвращаются (print'у)
        """
        return ' '.join(
            [self.name,
             str(self.sum_debts),
             str(self.sum_overdue)])

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        """Позволяет получать аттрибуты класса, с помощью:
        объект['аттрибут'] т.е. можно получить:
        name, sum_debts, sum_overdue, аналогично словарям."""
        return getattr(self, item)

    def as_dict(self):
        """Конвертировать в обычный словарь."""
        return asdict(self)

class Orders(UserList):
    """Слегка доработанный список.
    Ведет себя, как обычный список, только в консоль выводится иначе.
    """
    def __str__(self):
        """Аналогична функции из Order,
        только склеивает содержимое себя.
        Т.е. список.
        """
        return '\n'.join(map(str, self.data))


orders = Orders()  #  Создаем наш уникальный пустой (пока) список с разобранными блоками.
for block in alltext:
    for relationship in block['relationships']:
        # Создаем объект нашего Order и отдаем ему ветку relationship.
        # Пусть сам разбирается, что с ней делать.
        # Созданный объект Order добавляем в наш уникальный список orders, как и в любой другой список.
        orders.append(Order(relationship['relationship']))

# Печатаем содержимое нашего списка.
print(orders)
print('--------\n')


# Примеры того, как взаимодействовать с тем, что мы сгенерили:
# Cам orders не буду трогать. Это обычный list, только функция печати другая.

print(orders[0]) # Печатаем наш датакласс из первой строки.
print(orders[0].name) # Печатаем имя из первой строки.
print(orders[0]['name']) # Аналогично.
print(orders[1].sum_debts) # Печатаем sum_debts из второй строки.
print(orders[1].sum_overdue) # Печатаем sum_overdue из второй строки.
print(orders[0].as_dict()) # Печатаем первый элемент списка в виде словаря, а не dataclass'a.
```

`dataclass` потребляет меньше оперативы, чем `dict`, но больше процессорного времени.

А это для скучных:

```
orders = []
for block in alltext:
    for relationship in block['relationships']:
        orders.append({
            'name': relationship['relationship']['name'],
            'sum_debts': relationship['relationship']['debts'][0]['sum'],
            'sum_overdue': relationship['relationship']['overdueDebts'][0]['sum'],
        })

print(orders)
```

Comment: Сорри, но я не могу понять как это роботает. Можно это сделать с помощю функций или что-то похожего?